# Trim special characters powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm using Get-ChildItem to find files on remote computers and piping them using Select-Object to only return the file name it finds. The problem is, it's returning @{Name=File.txt}, but I only want the file name.

```
$TraName = Get-ChildItem \\$comp\c$\ -Filter File*.txt | Select-Object Name
$TraName
echo "Found $TraName on $comp" | out-file c:\Names.txt -append
```

I've tried using .Trim(@{Name=}), but it wont trim special characters.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm no PS expert, but isn't that returning your file list as variables? shouldn't you just be able to call out the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-Object Property` returns a PowerShell custom object with a single property. When custom objects are converted to strings PSH's hash litteral (`@{name=value;name=vale;…}`) notation is used.

If you want to select just one property then just use `.Property` to do so, PowerShell does the right thing for arrays (you get an array of the value of that property):

```
$TraName = (Get-ChildItem \\$comp\c$\ -Filter File*.txt).Name
```